# Holo theme not found with correct SDK

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-theme

I am receiving the following error when compiling an Android project using SDK 4.1.2:

`/res/values-v14/styles.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:Theme.Holo.Light'.`

The values-v14 resource directory is the only place this theme is referenced.

The uses-sdk in my manifest is `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>` and the project SDK is set to build with Android 4.1.2 with the Google APIs.

Can anyone give me some idea of what might be occurring?

I am using the latest version of Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Turns out there was some junk that IDEA imported from Eclipse. Cleaning out the old SDK references in Eclipse fixed the IDEA stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this was a project imported from Eclipse, I had to go back and change the SDK built against to 4.1.2 in Eclipse, and then IDEA decided to play nice.